# Hiding a grapch in crystal reports if there's only one period

Tags: graph, crystal-reports, formula

I'm relatively new to Crystal Reports and I'm getting trouble with this:

I created a graph on the group header section so that it shows the sales by client per month. Each client gets its own graph. The thing is that I'm getting blank graphs for the clients that didn't buy anything on the period. I tried to used the following code on the "Suppress if blank" option in the Section Expert in order to hide the blank graphs, but it didn't work:

IF COUNT(T_CMDE.ID_CMDE_LINE)=0 THEN TRUE

Any help is much apreciated.

Comment: What will be the value in database if client doesn't buy in a particular month

Answer (score 0):

Go to your section expert and choose the header the graph is in. Next to "Supress (No Drill-Down)" click the x-2 formula button.

[image: http://imgur.com/anOunTA]

Try:

```
{T_CMDE.ID_CMDE_LINE}=0
```

That should suppress any header that has a value of 0 for that field.